# The precedence of java boolean

Tags: java, boolean

`&&` is supposed to have higher precedence than `||`:

```
    int a = 10;
    System.out.println(a==10 || --a==9 && a==8);
    System.out.println(a);
```

this prints true, and 10. It seems that it checks only the first part and if its true the second never executes.

If I do `a==9` then the second part seems to evaluate and prints 9. Can someone explain why this is happening? Isn't `&&` supposed to evaluate first?

Edit: I see it. `a==10 ||  --a==9 && a==8` transforms into `(a==10) || (a==9 && a==8)` So if the first one evaluates to true it short circuits. Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: no Higher precedence, it just goes from left to right..

Comment: @gtgaxiola Careful when you say no precedence. If there was no precedence. If there was no precedence that expression would evaluate to true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.out.println(a==10 ||  --a==9 && a==8);
```

equal to

```
System.out.println((a==10) ||  (((--a)==9) && (a==8)));
```

Java evaluates `||` first. Find out that left part (a==10) is `true` and derive that no mater what is in right part result anyway will be `true`

**PS**: it is common trick to write

```
if(obj != null && obj.isSomething) { ... }
```

to prevent **NPE**

Answer (score 3):

If you evaluate `(a==10) || (b == 9)` (which is an `OR` operation),
if the first clause is `true`, then the entire expression must be `true` (because it's OR) and the second clause will not be executed for reasons of optimization.

Code is executed from left to right, so you'll hit the first `TRUE` therefore your entire statement will be `TRUE`, and the remainder of your statement will not be executed

If your first clause is `false`, then only will the second clause be evaluated.

If you use  `(a==10) | (b == 9)` both clauses will be evaluated.

If you want to be certain of the precedence of your operators, you should use brackets

Answer (score 3):

It's useful to look at expressions as trees.

```
a==10 ||  --a==9 && a==8
```

In this example, the top of the tree is an OR. The left branch is an EQUALS, and the right branch is an AND whose left and right branch are both EQUALS.

Since I'm awful at graphics, it would look something like:

```
    OR
   /   \-----
  =          \
 / \         AND
a  10       /   \
           =     =
          / \   / \
       --a   9 a   8
```

The "precedence" that you're talking about, orders this tree. But it doesn't necessarily change execution order. Because in this case, this is true if the first branch is true, so no need to check the second branch.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have anything to do with higher precedence in this case.  Look up lazy evaluation.  The operation will be evaluated from left to right and will find that `a==10` is true and stop there.

Look at the comments in http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/ under order of evaluation

Answer (score 0):

```
 || and && are short circuit operators they don't evaluate the right hand side expression 
 if the left hand side is true.
 So (--a) is never executed as (a==10) left hand side is true
 Therefore the value of a remains same.
 **& and | operators that always evaluate both sides.
```